# Python sorting an ordered dictionary and the resulting .items() iterator

Tags: python, sorting, ordereddictionary

How to sort an OrderedDict definitely does exist elsewhere on the site.  An example of how to do this is:

```
foo = OrderedDict(sorted(ordered_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][0]))
```

To explain, I have an OrderedDict of List and so it is the first entry in the list of the keys of the OrderedDict that the sorting takes place on.  I return the sorted collection as a new OrderedDict called foo.  Great.

But then my question revolves around foo.items().  If I were to then do:

```
for idx, row in foo.items():
```

The values which are specified by row do come back in sorted order proving that sort above worked.  However, the idx variable is in crazy random order and does not correlate with the position in the new OrderedDict, perhaps it is the position in the old OrderedDict, that is what I speculate.

So then my question is how would I get it so both the row comes back sorted (as it is now) and the idx increments 1 at a time in increasing order?

**UPDATE**

```
foo = list(OrderedDict(sorted(ordered_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][0])).values())

for idx in range(0, len(foo)):
    row = foo[idx]
```

This is something like what I want to do.  The key does not matter of the original dict to me.  What I need is the item sorted by the first value in the list contained in the values of the dict and then to be able to say what position in the list that row is (for later use and not seen in the snippet above).  So yes while the input must be a dict, I don't need a new dict, I just need a list.

Comment: Recall that this is a *dictionary*, not a list. It doesn't have *indices*, it has *keys*. When you sort it, the same keys correspond to the same values. So if you start with `{0: [5], 1: [3]}` then when you sort it you'll have `{1: [3], 0: [5]}`. If you want the keys to just be integers from 0 to n-1 (where n is the length), then I'd recommend just using a list instead.

Comment: Can you add some example data? From your question it is really not clear what you mean.

Comment: @Nathan Yes, I suppose in the end a list would do it for me.  The input is OrderedDict and that will not change.  The key is junk and can be thrown away, it is the list in the values that I am interested in and I simply just need the get the index of this new list when iterating over my new structure.  I have.an update to my question which demonstrates the way I can achieve it and let's see how clean it is.  I just go lost on idx being the key because the key happens to be 0,1,2,... and supposed something more magical was going on.

Comment: @demongolem Why don't you just use `foo = sorted(ordered_dict.values())`? No need to create another dict and no need to specify a key since lists are compared by their elements in order (unless you want to have `[1, 3] <= [1, 2]` cause that's what your current implementation assumes).